# How to set active profile programmatically for any environment?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-boot-test

I want to set active profile host dependent for any envrionment and cannot find an environment independent hook.

Following factory will set the active profile before application context will build.

**/META-INF/spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=MyApplicationContextInitializer
```

**MyApplicationContextInitializer.java**

```
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ca) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = ca.getEnvironment();
        environment.addActiveProfile("myHost");
    }
}
```

If this example is executed in a mock environment by JUnit ...

***Test.java**

```
...
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
...
```

... following will be logged.

```
...
... RestControllerTests   : The following profiles are active: myHost
...
```

**but profile *myHost* is not active and default profile will be used in context of JUnit!**

A test as Java Application and JUnit with VM arguments works ...

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=myHost
```

I use a war packaged spring-boot-starter-web app and programmatically profile shall be set and used in any environment

- Java Application
- JUnit
- Servlet Container

How do I set the profile **programmatically** for any environmnet?

I do not want to use VM arguments or environemt variables because the profile shall be set by the current host name.

Answer (score 14):

Simplest answer after a lot of googling :)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleMain2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment = new StandardEnvironment();
      environment.setActiveProfiles("dev");

      SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(ExampleMain2.class);
      sa.setEnvironment(environment);
      sa.setAdditionalProfiles("remote","live");
      sa.run(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and I finally solved it implementing the ActiveProfilesResolver interface.

In your case you could do something like this:

```
public class MyActivateProfilesResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {

    @Override
    public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {
         // some code to find out your active profiles
         return new String[] {"myHost"};
    }
}
```

And then you need to link your test with your resolver like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = MyActivateProfilesResolver.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a thing as setting active profile dynamically (programmatically) at runtime once the application is running, any modification to the profile will not have any effect on the loaded beans and properties files.

However, before running the application you can configure the available profiles of the application. for example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplicationWithSysProperty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, 
        PROFILE_NAME);
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplicationWithSysProperty.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that could be achieved with an EnvironmentPostProcessor ans still have an impact on the running environment? My attempts failed.

```
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class EnvtPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment env, SpringApplication application) {
    if ((env.acceptsProfiles("bar1") || env.acceptsProfiles("bar2"))
            && !(env.acceptsProfiles("foo1") || env.acceptsProfiles("foo2"))) {
        env.addActiveProfile("foo1");
    }
}
}
```

NB: don't forget to register the processor in src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.mygroup.myapp.EnvtPostProcessor
```

When I only apply the "bar2" active profile, the "foo1" profile is added to the environnement as an active profile, before application context initialization; but not all beans are found eventually (as they are in the originally complete active profiles list use case).

Maybe that's because of the dependencies (Azure for Spring Cloud connection, by the way) : I end up with no OAuth2UserService found for my ActiveDirectoryConfigurer.